# Regular Expression for the language that requires one symbol to occur at least once

Tags: formal-languages, regular-expressions

I am trying to figure out the simplest way to do this using a regular expression.

- Three symbols a, b, c.
- The sequence length is unlimited, i.e. *.
- The symbol a must be somewhere in the sequence at least once, but can appear more than once.
- The sequence may have only a.

More formally, $\{ w \in \{a,b,c\}^* ~|~ \#_a(w)\ge 1 \}$, where $\#_a(w)$ is the number
of $a$s in $w$.

The best I get is

> $( ( b \mid c )^*\, a\, ( b \mid c )^* )^+$

Is that the simplest way?

Comment: You ask for EBNF, but you give a regular expression. What is it you want? Also, what does "The sequence can have only a" mean; one one of something (what?) or only symbols $a$?

Comment: It is actualy part of a grammar, thus the EBNF. sepp2k hit the nail on the head with his answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest regular expression I can think of for this is $\left(a \mid b \mid c\right)^* a \left(a \mid b \mid c\right)^*$. This is simpler than yours by the following measures of complexity:

- It contains less nesting (and fewer parentheses in general)
- It contains fewer quantifiers

Comment: @GuyCoder I meant the number of characters in the regex. Mine has 17, yours has 20.

Comment: @sepp2k: Counting superfluous parentheses is not fair.

Comment: This is simpler because it is nested only to depth one, which makes reasoning about it much easier than if the depth were two or more. In fact, I vote this the simplest and clearest possible.

Comment: @Raphael I don't need to count superfluous parentheses to have fewer of them. His expression has 3 pairs of non-superfluous parentheses with a nesting-depth of 2. Mine has 2 pairs and a nesting depth of 1.

Answer (score 5):

As the expression is to be part of a parser (i.e. should be efficiently checkable), it might be a good idea to make the regular expression unambiguous:

$\qquad \displaystyle (b \mid c)^*\, a\, (a \mid b \mid c)^*$

describes the same language but avoids ambiguity by distinguishing the *first* $a$ in a matching word. Wether this has an impact depends on the way your parser generator works.

This is the same written as diagram, with the token names the OP uses:
[image]
*<sup>Image by Guy Coder.</sup>*

Comment: Also, it is just that tiny bit shorter than Sepp's. :]

Comment: @GuyCoder: This one *is* unambiguous. I guess your problem lies elsewhere?